# Nested XML element throwing exception

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

How to get first Status by its `<StatusType>` element `<Code>` is D. This LINQ works, but re sharp says `x.Element("StatusType")` possible nullreferenceexpection.

```
var aaa = track.Descendants("Status")
     .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Element("StatusType") != null && 
                          x.Element("StatusType").Element("Code").Value == "D");
```

XML:-

```
<Activity>
<ActivityLocation>
<Address>
<City>WILSLLE</City>
<StateProvinceCode>oR</StateProvinceCode>
<PostalCode>978880</PostalCode>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
</Address>
<Code>M7</Code>
<Description>RECEIVER</Description>
<SignedForByName>abc</SignedForByName>
</ActivityLocation>
<Status>
<StatusType>
<Code>D</Code>
<Description>DELIVERED</Description>
</StatusType>
<StatusCode>
<Code>KB</Code>
</StatusCode>
</Status>
<Date>20150504</Date>
<Time>085100</Time>
</Activity>
<Activity>
<ActivityLocation>
<Address>
<City>TUALATIN</City>
<StateProvinceCode>OR</StateProvinceCode>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
</Address>
</ActivityLocation>
<Status>
<StatusType>
<Description>OUT FOR DELIVERY</Description>
</StatusType>
<StatusCode>
<Code>DS</Code>
</StatusCode>
</Status>
<Date>20150504</Date>
<Time>045600</Time>
</Activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that some `StatusType` node does not contain the `Code` tag itself thus it will return null and `.Value` throws a null reference exception. It's better to type-cast your value as follows because explicit casting operators is much safer than accessing Value property since it checks for `null` first.

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("Status")
                 .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Element("StatusType") != null && 
                           (string)x.Element("StatusType").Element("Code") == "D");
```

Also, if you are pretty sure that your filter query will return just 1 node only then use [SingleOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx) otherwise [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.100).aspx) is better option.